# Displaying a name with a highscore (iPhone app)

Tags: string, plist, nsdictionary

What I want to do is add a name to my score list. As of now I have a name being saved as an NSString and I have my scored being saved as an integer and later on I will want to order these from high to low (scores). Below is my code that is saving the score as a integer out to a plist and then on my high score view I'm calling that score from the plist and displaying it. I think I'm going to need to use an NSDictionary to save the string for the name and the integer for the score. This is where I'm stuck and if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *scoresListPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"scores.plist"];

scoresList = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:scoresListPath] retain];

if (scoresList == nil) {
    scoresList = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];




- (void)addHighScore:(float)finalScore {
    [scoresList addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:finalScore]];

    [scoresList sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *scoresListPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"scores.plist"];
    [scoresList writeToFile:scoresListPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic idea correct, but instead of saving just an array of NSNumbers, all you have to do is save an array of NSDictionaries.

So keep your NSMutableArray the way it is, and simply add scores to it:

```
NSDictionary *score = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys: theName, @"name", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:finalScore], @"finalScore", nil];
[scoresList addObject: score];
```

The scoreList will still write out its plist properly, because the NS[Mutable]Array contains dictionaries which contains only numbers and strings, and these know how to write themselves out to a plist (see NSCoder).

When you read back your array, the -objectAtIndex:i will be an NSDictionary, and you can get the name with -objectForKey:@"name" and the score with -objectForKey:@"finalScore".